# Phase transitions. Conceptual link of my intuitive notions and definition of Georgii's book in terms of probabilities

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

In his classic book O. H. Georgii ([Gibbs Measures and Phase Transitions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3110250292)) in Chapter 2 [p. 28](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=3vMCnvMH-hkC&pg=PA535&dq=Georgii+O.+H.+Phase+transitions&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=Q23mUcbiOffi4APj1oGQCg#v=onepage&q=Georgii%20O.%20H.%20Phase%20transitions&f=false) define the concept of phase transition follows.

> **Definition** *A potencial $\Phi$ will be said exhibit a phase transitions if $|\mathcal{G}(\Phi)|>1$.*

In other words the set of Gibbs measures $\mathcal{G}(\Phi)$ for a potential $\Phi$ associated with a physical model has more than one Gibbs measure $\mu$. But for me this definition is'' hard to swallow "and does not seem intuitive.I think my difficulty is that being a mathematician I could not understand what exactly is a state of equilibrium in models of statistical mechanics. For example in the Ising model and Potts model.

- > The first intuitive notion that I have to equilibrium state (which may be a mistaken analogy) is the solid state, liquid and gaseous water for example. Also called phases solid, liquid and gaseous respectively. Therefore understand the term phase transition as the transition from one equilibrium state to another state of equilibrium. For example, the ice turning into liquid water.
  >   [image]
- > The second intuitive notion that I have (which may be full of misunderstandings) about the phase transition is when the state of equilibrium of a model ferromagnetic spin moves to another state (equilibrium?) due to increasing temperature.

My question assumes that the definition of Giorgii is just a technical way of describing my intuitive notions.

*How do I make the conceptual link of my intuitive notions of phase trantions with the definition of Georgii's book in terms of probabilities?*

> **Question.** *More precisely wonder if there is a conceptual definition of **equilibrium state** and **phase transition** that are acceptable in statistical mechanics that can provide a link between my poor **intuitive notions** and the concept of **phase transition** in terms of probabilities in Georgii's book?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I really don't have time to answer. But it might help you to have a look at introductory books on statistical mechanics. Alternatively (moving from the math side), you might benefit from reading more student-friendly introductions to this topic. Two nice ones are http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/9210.2732 (in particular section 2) and http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905031 .

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thanks for the references. I'll read carefully these two references. Unfortunately there is no statistical mechanics courses at my university. At the moment I have counting on his patience. Thank you very much Velenik.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any book for physicists discussing the abstract mathematical framework (Gibbs measures, etc.). On the other hand, there are some online lecture notes for equilibrium statistical mechanics that I find quite good (they are for physics students, but they discuss the mathematical framework and explain its relevance). These notes are by Yoshi Oono, and can be found at http://www.yoono.org/Y_OONO_official_site/download.html . The relevant file is SMHyperS12.pdf (see the part on the course Phys 504 S12). I think that this might provide the type of explanations you want.